# how to repeat a failed transaction ? node pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, node-postgres

I want to delete some rows with transactions and maybe a internet error occurs or something else and its failed. How can I repeat this function ?

maybe:

```
const delete = await DeleteBooking({db_name, booking_id: data.booking_id});

maybe its failed what to do now ?
```